# One mocked class works fine, the other returns null

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I am mocking 2 classes in one of my unit tests, defining the behavior with Mockito. When and then calling the functions.

One of the mocked classes works exactly as expected, the other returns `null`.  I can't figure out what the difference is between the two.

**QueryServiceTest.java**

```
@Import({ QueryServiceTestConfig.class })
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class QueryServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private QueryService queryService;
    @MockBean
    private ElasticConnectionService elasticConnectionService;
    @MockBean
    private HBaseConnectionService hbaseConnectionService;

    @Test
    public void test_getRecordsFromQuery() throws IOException {

        // creation of sample data for inputs and outputs goes here

        // This mock works when called from queryService.getRecordsFromQuery()
        when(elasticConnectionService.getRowIdsFromQuery(filterParams, testIndex)).thenReturn(getRowIdsFromQuery_result);

        List<JSONObject> matches = queryService.getMatchingRowIds(getRowIdsFromQuery_result);

        // matchesArray is directly defined to make sure its exactly the same as in queryService.getRecordsFromQuery()
        JSONObject matchesArray = new JSONObject("{\"testTable\":[\"testUUID\"]}");

        // This mock fails when called from queryService.getRecordsFromQuery()
        when(hbaseConnectionService.getRowsByIDs(matchesArray)).thenReturn(getRowsByIDs_result);

        // This returns getRowsByIDs_result as expected
        JSONArray test = hbaseConnectionService.getRowsByIDs(matchesArray);

        // This returns null
        JSONArray actual = new JSONArray(queryService.getRecordsFromQuery(filterParams, testIndex));
    }
}
```

**QueryService.java**

```
@Service
public class QueryService {

    @Autowired
    private ElasticConnectionService elasticConnectionService;
    @Autowired
    private HBaseConnectionService hbaseConnectionService;
    @Autowired
    private PSQLConnectionService psqlConnectionService;

    public String getRecordsFromQuery(
                    Map<String,String> filterParams,
                    String tablename) throws IOException {
        /**
         * Get records that match simple key/value filters
         */

        // This mocked method returns exactly what was expected
        List<List<JSONObject>> lookupsList = elasticConnectionService.getRowIdsFromQuery(filterParams, tablename);

        List<JSONObject> matches = getMatchingRowIds(lookupsList);

        // matchesArray is exactly the same as in the test class
        JSONObject matchesArray = new JSONObject("{\"testTable\":[\"testUUID\"]}");

        // This returns null
        JSONArray hbResults = hbaseConnectionService.getRowsByIDs(matchesArray);

        return hbResults.toString(4);
    }
}
```

**QueryServiceTestConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class QueryServiceTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public QueryService queryService() {
        return new QueryService();
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticConnectionService elasticConnectionService() {
        return new ElasticConnectionService();
    }

    @Bean
    public HBaseConnectionService hbaseConnectionService() {
        return new HBaseConnectionService();
    }

    @Bean
    public PSQLConnectionService psqlConnectionService() {
        return new PSQLConnectionService();
    }
}
```

What confuses me most is that in `queryService.getRecordsByQuery()`, the `elasticConnectionService.getRowIDsFromQuery()` mock returns what was expected, but the `hbaseConnectionService.getRowsByIDs()` mock returns `null`.

The elastic and hbase connection service classes are both defined in the same folder and the only annotation they have is `@Service`.  I would think I had configured something wrong if both failed, but the fact that the `elasticConnectionService` call works as expected tells me something else is happening.

Comment: What is the package of JSONObject?

Comment: @StvnBrkdll I'm using org.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the package of `JSONObject` is `org.json`, `JSONObject`'s equals method looks like:

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
            return object == null || object == this;
        }
```

Since the instance of `matchesArray` in `QueryService` is different than the instance in `QueryServiceTest`, the `equals()` method will return false.

Try changing this:

```
when(hbaseConnectionService.getRowsByIDs(matchesArray)).thenReturn(getRowsByIDs_result);
```

to this, and see if your results change:

```
when(hbaseConnectionService.getRowsByIDs(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(getRowsByIDs_result);
```

I think you also may be able to do this:

```
when(hbaseConnectionService.getRowsByIDs(Mockito.eq(matchesArray))).thenReturn(getRowsByIDs_result);
```

or:

```
when(hbaseConnectionService.getRowsByIDs(Matchers.eq(matchesArray))).thenReturn(getRowsByIDs_result);
```

Because under the hood, the `Matchers.eq()` method probably calls `JSONObject.equals()`, the Matcher probably won't work (I didn't check the source code for `Matchers.eq()`).

In general, when setting up a mock method call, you want to wrap your `parameter(s)` in one of Mockito's Matcher's methods. Unfortunately, that won't work in your scenario.

(Note that the class Mockito extends Matchers)

Comment: Thanks!  I can use `any()`, which in this case is ok, but I tried using `eq(matchesArray)` and that still doesn't match.  In this case I can get away with using `any()`, but I'd prefer to be more specific with my testing if possible, is there a way to get `JSONObject` to behave as expected with Mockito?

Comment: Because of the way JSONObject's equals() method is implemented, no, you can't get it to behave the way you hoped (i.e. you can't use Matchers)

Comment: To make your code more easily testable, and more flexible, consider passing matchesArray as a parameter to getRecordsFromQuery(). This will allow you to use Matchers in your unit test, and also make your method more flexible.

Comment: Well, before I go digging for a new JSON library, is there one you'd recommend that plays nicely with Mockito?

Comment: Tale a look at Jackson